# Fabric.js canvas blending mode

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to set "globalCompositeOperation" for the fabric canvas object? Need the canvas objects to behave like in this example:

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/28/blending-features-in-canvas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

```
canvas.getContext().globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
```